# How do I access the nth record of the nth column of the nth dataframe in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Let's say I have the following list of dataframes

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y1 = 3:12, y2 = 3:12)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y2 = 2:11, y2 = 3:12)
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y3 = 4:13, y2 = 3:12)
df4 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y4 = 5:14, y2 = 3:12)
x <- list(df, df2, df3, df4)
```

How would I access the nth record of the nth column of the nth dataframe of the list?

Would it be some form of x[[n,n]]?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `x[[n]][n,n]`

Comment: That's how you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the nth record of the nth column of the nth dataframe of the list, you can do

```
x[[n]][n,n]
```

For example:

```
x[[1]][1,2]
```

will return the value of first row, second column, first dataframe of the list.